# I want to run some command related to SONAR SCANNER in GITLAB

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Is there any demo or useful command for run sonar scanner in YML file.Because my solar scanner command is not working with gitlab runner.

$ sonar-scanner
 /bin/bash: line 92: sonar-scanner: command not found
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: did you check the sonarqube [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/gitlab-cicd/#header-3) yet ?

Comment: yes @NicolasPepinster 
sonar-scanner command is working with SSH connection but its not working with gitlab runner.